# Page loads very slow

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good day everyone!

Please, I've tried all I can to resolve this issue, all to know avail.

The index page loads faster, but when I try logging in to the dashboard and accessing every other pages under PHP session, I keep getting these errors on my JS console - moreover, the pages loads very slowly under PHP session.

These are the errors:

```
> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://flutterwave.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.


5[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See <URL> for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: <URL>
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for https://azuredate.com/asset/css/bootstrap.css.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
33XHR finished loading: POST "<URL>".
jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
n._evalUrl @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
ua @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
append @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
K @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
html @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
success @ dashboard:1074
i @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
z @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
load_unread_messages @ dashboard:1068
(anonymous) @ dashboard:1078
i @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
J @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
64XHR finished loading: GET "<URL>".
7Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/index.all.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for https://azuredate.com/asset/css/bootstrap.css.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
2DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/index.all.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/index.all.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://assets.flutterwave.com/assets/popper.min.js.map: 
HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Meanwhile, below are the JS files am loading - which works perfectly fine on my localhost

    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- menu js aim -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/jquery.menu-aim.js"> </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
    <!-- //menu js aim -->
        
    <!-- for bootstrap working -->
     <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- //for bootstrap working -->
    <!-- for smooth scrolling -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/move-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/js/easing.js"></script>
I've tried using a jquery cdn for this particular issue, but it's not working. I have also tried a higher version of jQuery and it's not working either.
```

The url is https://azuredate.com

Help a brother in need, please!

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your errors it says that "a slow network is detected", I would guess that is likely the issue. Does the dashboard load eventually? I think you should resolve each issue raised by the errors one by one, that missing cookie at the start could have a flow-on effect of failed retrievals, you are getting a heap of 404 not founds. Perhaps try other sources for those files, and test if that works better?

Comment: The dashboard loads, but it takes ages to do so, compared to how fast it loads on my localhost...